# How to get google search results with page rank > 2

Tags: php, google-api, google-search

I am currently working on a software. One of the tasks is to show google search results for a bunch of keywords. The results need to have a PR higher than two. Additionally, all websites must be older than 2010.

(I can get the PR of any URL.) Now, there are a few ways how I could solve my task.
First, I could run all the links google is returning me through my engine and check on every single one if it has a PR > 2. As you may realise, it will take very long to do just that(since the server has to establish a new connection to every single url).

At this moment, I have not figured out another way to do this but I need one. Is there any method to filter the results via $_GET parameters on google directly? I know there is a better way to do that but I haven't found one.

I am thankful for every fresh perspective on this!

PS: I am working with the Google Search API and PHP